# How to install exe versions of linux utilities on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, wget, busybox

I am aware that we can get .exe versions of many linux utilities. I happen to have wget.exe, curl.exe and busybox.exe. But how can I install them so that instead of typing

```
C:\Users\Rahul>cd downloads

C:\Users\Rahul\Downloads>wget
```

I can straight away type

```
C:\Users\Rahul>wget
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't copy them to `C:\windows\system32`.

Instead, place them in a sensible location and add that location to your `%PATH%` environment variable.

- If you don't install the utilities in their default location (specified by the website or installer), you might place such utilities in a dedicated folder such as `C:\bin\` or `C:\programs\`. I prefer this to a path in `Program Files` in case you install a program that doesn't handle spaces in path names very well.
- You can (permanently) add a folder to your `%PATH%` in `cmd.exe` like this:

  ```
  setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\bin\"
  ```

  (Note that the `set` command will only change your path for the current session. `setx` changes it permanently.)
- *Note:* the command above adds the folder to the *end* of your path, so a program anywhere else will take precedence if it has the same name as one in the folder you just added. If you want the folder you add to have precedence over everything else, instead use this command:

  ```
  setx PATH "C:\bin\;%PATH%"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of me. It was pretty simple, I just had to copy wget.exe to C:\windows\system32.

Comment: Or: put them in any other location and adjust the [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) that Windows uses for searching.

Comment: @Arjan True... But my my method seems simpler.

Comment: Better idea.  Put such utilities in a separate directory and modify your %PATH% to include that directory.